# pandas.to_datetime() how to convert from local timezone to UTC unix timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, timezone

I have a list of date values in form of 'YYYY-MM-DD'. These values are in timezone of local PC (that is not known for me). These values are loaded as a Series in Pandas dataframe and I want to convert them into UTC timestamp.

1. If I use very simple code:

```s
ts = pd.to_datetime(s, format="%Y-%m-%d")
print(ts[0])
print(int(ts[0].timestamp()))
print(ts[0].strftime("%d.%m.%Y %Z"))
```

It gives me output:

```
2021-01-01 00:00:00
1609459200   --> this is 'Friday, January 1, 2021 0:00:00 UTC'
01.01.2021
```

i.e. it takes source strings as UTC and put it in UTC. But my source string is in localtime and output is not correct.

2. Then I found an option to provide timezone info in source strings this way:

```
s = pd.Series(['2021-01-01 Europe/Moscow', '2021-01-02 Europe/Moscow'])
ts = pd.to_datetime(s, format="%Y-%m-%d %Z")
print(ts[0])
print(int(ts[0].timestamp()))
print(ts[0].strftime("%d.%m.%Y %Z"))
```

And it gives me result that I really need:

```
2021-01-01 00:00:00+03:00
1609448400 --> this is correct 'Thursday, December 31, 2020 21:00:00 UTC'
01.01.2021 MSK
```

But timezone name is hardcoded here.

3. So, I need to get a local timezone name from a PC where my code works. I tried this way:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz
print(datetime.now(tz.tzlocal()).tzname())
```

and it gives me output `MSK`. But the problem with this output - when I try to use it for Pandas.to_datetime - it gives me an error:

```
s = pd.Series(['2021-01-01 MSK', '2021-01-02 MSK'])
ts = pd.to_datetime(s, format="%Y-%m-%d %Z")
```

*ValueError: time data '2021-01-01 MSK' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %Z' (match)*

So, I see following ways forward:

- either somehow get a full timezone name `Europe/Moscow` instead of short `MSK` from my python code,
- or make `pandas.to_datetime()` format option `%Z` recognize short form of timezone name `MSK`,
- or somehow pre-process source strings before importing it to pandas (least desirable path, so I haven't studied it yet).

I'm a bit stuck to chose a way forward here. May you give me advice which way gives me better code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`Series.dt.tz_localize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize.html):

```
from dateutil import tz

s = pd.Series(['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02'])
ts = pd.to_datetime(s, format="%Y-%m-%d").dt.tz_localize(tz.tzlocal())
```